section_plot for temperature but with the date instead of distance
I have somlit temperature data for several depths, for each week from 1996 to 2019, and I'd like to make a graph of it. I've tried using ggplot2 without much success because I'd like a smoothed graph like on a section plot. the problem with my dataset is that I don't have the distance but the date, so I can't get a nice graph...
Does anyone know a function, or how to modify the section_plot function or my dataset to make it work?
Here's my code :
section_plot(somlit, x = "DATE", y = "PROFONDEUR", z = "TEMPERATURE", add_bottom = NULL, interpolate = TRUE, sampling_indicator = "none")
